# Will ichthyophthiriasis medicine harm my betta if he doesnt actually have ich?

Tags: health, aquarium, medicines, diseases, betta

A few days ago I noticed a spot on my betta's side just next to his gills. It wasn't completely white in color but definitely lighter than the rest of his body. I tested his water and there was an ammonia spike of 2 ppm so I did a 30% water change and tested again the next day and it was at 1 ppm, then I did another change and got it down to zero. I hoped maybe it was just from the stress resulting from the ammonia spike but on the third day I noticed more spots on the top of his head. Not white but definitely lighter in color, just the same as the spot near his gills.

I searched everything and the only thing these spots resemble is ichthyophthiriasis but everything I've read said that ich spots were completely white in color. He hasn't been eating as much, isn't as active and hangs out at the bottom of his tank in his little napping spot for most of the day he wasn't even interested in the live brine shrimp and that's his absolute favorite.

I treated his 5 gallon tank with API Super Ick Cure and within 10 minutes he already was more active. Once a week I skip feeding him for a day to avoid overfeeding and that day is today, so I'm not sure if he would eat more. I'm just worried that maybe the spots could be abrasions and treating him may do more harm than good.

But at the same time I don't think there would be abrasions because he doesn't have anything in his tank that could cause physical harm unless he rammed himself into his hides (I have 2 small hides, some amazon sword plants and moss balls, he's also the only animal in the tank so it couldn't have been an injury from a fight I didn't see).